# I want to close the react-select menu when scrolled outside of menu list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

There is a `closeMenuOnScroll` prop in the official react-select documentation which states the following: `closeMenuOnScroll` prop

However, when I set `closeMenuOnScroll={() => true}` prop on the  component, it closes the menu even if I scroll inside of it (I can't scroll the menu options, because it is automatically closed).
What I try to achieve is to go through (scroll) the menu items when I scroll inside the react-select component and close the menu if I scroll out of it.

Thanks.

```
<Select
   options={options}
   onChange={handleChange}
   closeMenuOnScroll={() => true}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation:](https://react-select.com/props)
If you pass a function, the menu will close whenever the function returns true.
And this is what happens in your case, the menu closes on *any* scroll action, even within the select menu.

If you don't pass a function to the prop but just true/false, then the menu should only close when the body scrolls.

If you want more granular control, for instance when your select is in a scrolleable div that is not the window/body: Use the function but put some checks in it.

```
closeMenuOnScroll={e => {
   if (e.target === refToYourScrolleableContainer) {
     return true
   } else {
     return false
   }
}}
```

You want to examine the scroll event in the function you give to the closeMenuOnScroll prop and determine if the scroll came from the window or body (or container), then return true. Otherwise return false and don't close the menu.

So I guess the easiest way to fix your issue is to do `closeMenuOnScroll={true}`